# How to configure Bugsnag with Resque::Failure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, bugsnag

I want to use Bugsnag to report failed Resque jobs. **How do I configure it?** The [documentation](https://bugsnag.com/docs/notifiers/ruby#configuration) specifically mentions integrations with Resque, but offers no guidance as to how.

Do I have to write a `Resque::Failure::Bugsnag` class? Did someone else already write it so I don't have to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bugsnag ruby gem is set up to automatically integrate with things like Resque. In theory all you need to do is add bugsnag and resque to your Gemfile:

```
gem "resque"
gem "bugsnag"
```

and https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-ruby/blob/master/lib/bugsnag/resque.rb will do the integration work for you.

*disclaimer: I work for Bugsnag, and commit to the bugsnag rubygem.*

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Conrad's excellent answer above, I made the following mistake which was preventing Resque jobs from appearing in Bugsnag:

Make sure to *append* to `Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes` in your Resque initializer. I was overwriting the array in the Resque initializer, which was probably (arbitrarily) being called after the Bugsnag initializer ran.

i.e., in `config/initializers/resque.rb`:

**Do:**

```
Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes ||= []
Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes << Resque::Failure::Redis
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
```

**Do not:**

```
Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis]
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, if you are using a different failure backend class (we're using `MultipleWithRetrySuppression` by https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry#failure-backend), you need to manually add `Bugsnag::Resque` to the array. For example:

```rb
(Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression.classes ||= []).push(
  Resque::Failure::Redis,
  Bugsnag::Resque
)
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::MultipleWithRetrySuppression
```